# How do you get the secret achievements in Valet Hero?

Tags: achievements, ios, valet-hero

I have been playing the game Valet Hero for 6 months, but have (as of yet) failed to get any of the secret achievements.

**What are the secret achievements in Valet Hero?**

Comment: I thought this was a joke question at first. Now I need to buy this.

Comment: It is pretty challenging.  Sometimes it can be frustrating.  Imagine Pac-Man, where the ghosts can be twice as fast as you, but don't seek you out.  Sometimes the other cars are nearly impossible to avoid.

Comment: @Grace: Openfeint is the platform on which the game is made/run.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have all of them yet, so I'm going to have to come back and edit this answer to include other ones, but here are the ones I have so far:

- **Sunday Drive** (5): Drive 50 miles.
- **Road Trip** (10): Drive 250 miles.
- **Out of Gas** (5): Take a full tank of gas to empty, in one go.
- **Refueled** (5): Let you gas meter fill up, to full, from empty.
- **Super Sized** (20): Achieve a combo level of 15 on any gold challenge.
- **Bad Driver** (5): Crash 100 times throughout your Valet Hero career. (Challenges only.)

Six down, seven to go.

These are pretty self-explanatory, although I think Super Sized is glitched. I got it (as well as the normal achievements Value Meal and Drive Thru) on silver challenges.